# JavaScript FileReader and Dynamic Tables

Tags: javascript, filereader

I am trying to upload a file and read its contents and then output the contents to a table. The information needs to be place on a new row whenever there is a > char in the string.

I am having a bit of an issue wrapping my head around how I can create a new 'tr' and then add data to the a cell 'td' in that row.

I am stuck on the `<tr>` and `<td>` and adding them dynamically with the contents from the file. I am sure I can use regex to look for the > char but that isn't really what I need help with. I am struggling with how I take the information after the > char and add it to a new row in the table.

UPDATE: Ok, so I am still not fully functional on what I am trying to do. I am uploading the file, reading it, and storing the information as an object. However, I can only do this for one instance. When I upload a text file there will be multiple DNA sequences in the file. Each sequence will have a sequence_id like this:

> 9013e1
>   ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCC
>   CCTGGAGGGTGGCCCCACCGGCCGAGACAGCGAGCATATGCAGGAAGCGGCAGGAATAAGGAAAAGCAGC
>   CTCCTGACTTTCCTCGCTTGGTGGTTTGAGTGGACCTCCCAGGCCAGTGCCGGGCCCCTCATAGGAGAGG
>   AAGCTCGGGAGGTGGCCAGGCGGCAGGAAGGCGCACCCCCCCAGCAATCCGCGCGCCGGGACAGAATGCC
>   CTGCAGGAACTTCTTCTGGAAGACCTTCTCCTCCTGCAAATAAAACCTCACCCATGAATGCTCACGCAAG
>   TTTAATTACAGACCTGAA

So, I am trying to read the file, find all sequence ID's and then sequences and I want an editable leading and trailing trim like so:

```
var objArray = [
    {
        'id':  '>9013e1',
        'sequence': 'ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCT...',
        'lead_trim': //get the value from a input from the user,
        'trail_trim': //same as above
    },
    {
        //another obj like above
    }
]
```

The sequence also needs to have a line break inserted after every 60 characters. Once I have processed the data in the text file correctly I then need to output the data to a table like I stated in my original post. The problem I am having is I am getting stuck on only being able to store information for one obj in my objArray.

Here is a look at my code...

```
function scanForSequences(event) {
    //Get the file from HTML input tag
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    var output = document.getElementById('table');

    if(file) {
        var sequenceArray = [];
        var objArray = [];
        var obj = {};
        var str = '';
        var subStr = '';
        //Create a new file reader
        var reader = new FileReader();
        //When the file reader loads
        reader.onload = function(evt) {
            //Add the contents of file to variable contents
            var contentsByLine = evt.target.result.split('\n');
            //Alert user the file upload has succeeded
            alert('File ' + file.name + ' has been uploaded!');

            for(var i = 0; i < contentsByLine.length; i++){
                if(contentsByLine[i].charAt(i) == '>'){
                    obj['id'] = contentsByLine[i];
                }else{
                    sequenceArray.push(contentsByLine[i]);
                    str = sequenceArray.toString();
                    subStr += str.substring(0, 60) + '\n';
                    str = str.substring(60);
                    obj['sequence'] = subStr;
                    obj['lead_trim'] = 0;
                    obj['trail_trim'] = 0;
                }
                objArray.push(obj);
                console.log(objArray);
            }

        }
        reader.readAsText(file);
    } else {
        alert('Failed to upload file!');
    }
    console.log(obj);
}

document.getElementById('fileItem').addEventListener('change', scanForSequences, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find my proposed solution in the fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/w6jbuqfy/

Here's an explanation of what's going on:

First we have a input of type file:

```
<input id="input" type="file">
```

We then attach an event listener to it to execute a function once a user has selected a file

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFile, false);
```

Inside the handleFile function, we use a FileReader to read the file.

```
var fileList = this.files;
var file = fileList[0];
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.readAsText(file);
```

Now fileReaders are asynchronous in nature, here i've got a simple interval that checks on the status of the filereader every 100ms.

```
  var checkReadyId = setInterval(function(){
    if(fr.readyState === 2){ //done
        window.clearInterval(checkReadyId);
      addFileDataToResults(fr.result);
    } else{
        console.log('not done yet');
    }
  }, 100);
```

FileReaders are done reading when their readyState is 2. So we check for that and once we are done, we can access the result from FileReader.result. As we read this as a text earlier above, we'll get a string back. We then pass this to our addFileDataToResults function.

```
  function addFileDataToResults(fileAsString){
    var resultsDiv = document.getElementById('results');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td = document.createElement('td');

    var linesInFile = fileAsString.split('\n');
    console.log(linesInFile);

    td.textContent = linesInFile[0];
    tr.appendChild(td);
    resultsDiv.appendChild(tr);
  }
```

What is happening here is that we grab the resultsDiv which is a real node in our HTML. We then use createElement which creates virtual nodes and put data into them. IN this case, we are simply putting the text of the first line into our file. Once we are done creating this virtual nodes, we use appendChild to our real node which turns the virtual node into a real node and you can see it in the html.

Hope this helps
:)

Comment: is it possible to use `fr.onload = addFileDataToResults2` instead of using intervals ?